# Does taking keys off of a MacBook keyboard void warranty

Tags: keyboard, hardware, warranty

I have some friends that try turning my MacBook Pro off (I always do it back to them if they do :) ).

My question is to make it harder for them to do that I could remove the power button key from my Mac. Would this void the warranty or not? I want to know this because I got AppleCare and do not want to waste that money

Comment: First of all tell your friends not to touch your computer in a mischievous way, and you in kind, _tell them to grow up!_  Secondly even if you pop the key off that will not stop it from being able to be shutoff, even removing the additional parts under the key as well.  You also risk breaking the key cap retainer so IMO it's not worth the risk of possibly damaging and or loosing keyboard parts just to keep your friends in check.  As to voiding the warranty probably not however I'd verify that with Apple Support first.

Comment: @user3439894 I do tell them not to. Since they do it to me I just spam tabs on their computer till it crashes :) We still have fun though. Just want to stop them. :)

Comment: @user3439894 Very well said. Totally unacceptable. I would tell such friends to odd off. More like 'friends'. There are real problems with doing what they do; on the other hand the fact the OP does it back makes it rather ridiculous to tell them off for it. And old though this is it most certainly does void the warranty at least now. I called about a key popping off and you're not even allowed to repair it yourself without voiding warranty. Unfortunate really but extremely frustrating too since yet another key popped off. It seems it's part of their relationship that it's OK  but agree w/you.

Comment: It's a shame that the question was framed this way because there are actually legitimate reasons to take keys off - for instance, if you spill liquid and it doesn't damage anything but just makes things sticky you're actually doing Apple a favor of sorts if you take the keys off and clean them off rather than making them replace something unnecessarily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you signed the AppleCare plan on the US, this is what the [legal document](http://www.apple.com/legal/sales-support/applecare/appmacnaen.html) states:

> **4. What is not Covered?**
>
> (ii) Damage caused by (…) (b) accident, abuse, misuse, liquid contact, fire, earthquake or other external cause, (c) operating the Covered Equipment outside the permitted or intended uses described by the manufacturer, or (d) service (including upgrades and expansions) performed by anyone who is not a representative of Apple or an Apple Authorized Service Provider (“AASP”);

I'm not a lawyer, but abuse and misuse may be applied to removing keys.
You may get away with it if you present it as an "upgrade", and you are an Apple Authorized Service Provider :)

Comment: Would they be able to detect that you removed the button if you can put it back on or not? If so does this mean the inly risk is if you break the button?

Comment: For anyone in the future: It does void the warranty absolutely. Even replacing a key that has popped off itself will void the warranty (I asked this a few weeks ago as it happened to me). And policy is policy - warranty is warranty.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you can do **anything** to your Apple device as long as the Apple Genius/tech cant see evidence of what was done. Which means that If popping off key caps and then putting them back on leaves no trace you are likely safe.

And I mean **no** trace. You would be surprised what an Apple genius/technician will find that you never noticed.

And third party replacements totally count as evidence of "tampering." So if you put a 3rd party SSD (or RAM, or whatever) in the Mac, put the Apple branded part back in before you take it in to Apple as they will take it out and say they can't and won't support non-Apple parts.

Comment: Will they be able to detect new keys?

Comment: They might. Make friends with an Apple Genius and ask them.

Comment: I rather not take the risk then. That is the 'key' to keeping warranty! Lol

Comment: That would be my advice, but some people are a little braver... hah.

Comment: I could do it but what is the point incase I end up loosing money?

Comment: @iProgram I know this is old but on my MacBook Pro 2017 (I think it is) a key popped off and when I called Apple to ask them if there was a way to replace it myself (since I"m extremely stressed - and worse) they told me it would void my warranty. Maybe it didn't back in 2015 but it certainly does now so if you didn't do that that's best. It's frustrating but it is what it is. Another key popped off my keyboard though not totally - yet. The R key first and the clip broke; they were able to fix it but they said next step would be replacing the top itself: no laptop for some days too!